# Error uploading image in yii2(SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)

Tags: image, upload, yii2

When i try to upload image i have got SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. The name of image saves in DB but image file(*in web/uploads*) doesn't. I don't know why. Help me please.
[image]
[image]

here is my cod from the view(update.php)

```
...    
<div class="user-form">

            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multi-part/form-data']]); ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'usersurname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'age')->textInput() ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'img')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                'options' => ['accept'=>'image/*'],
                'pluginOptions'=>[
                    'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/uploads']),
                    'allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
                    'showUpload' => true,
                    'initialPreview' => [
    //                    $model-> img ? Html::img($model-> img) : null, // checks the models to display the preview
                    ],
                    'overwriteInitial' => false,
                ],
            ]); ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'BUTTON_SAVE'), ['class' => 'btn siteColor']) ?>
            </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

        </div>
...
```

code from controller

```
...
    public function actionUpdate()
    {
        $user = $this->findModel();
        $model = new ProfileUpdateForm($user);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->update()) {
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }

    }
...
```

code from model

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\user\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use Yii;



class ProfileUpdateForm extends Model
{
    public $email;
    public $username;
    public $usersurname;
    public $data;
    public $age;
    public $from;
    public $time;
    public $img;
    public $file;

    /**
     * @var User
     */
    private $_user;

    public function __construct(User $user, $config = [])
    {
        $this->_user = $user;
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->email = $this->_user->email;
        $this->username = $this->_user->username;
        $this->usersurname = $this->_user->usersurname;
        $this->img = $this->_user->img;
//        $this-> file = $this->_user-> file;
        parent::init();
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['email', 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            [
                'email',
                'unique',
                'targetClass' => User::className(),
                'message' => Yii::t('app', 'ERROR_EMAIL_EXISTS'),
                'filter' => ['<>', 'id', $this->_user->id],
            ],
            [['email','usersurname', 'username', 'img'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['img'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, gif'],
            ['age', 'integer'],
        ];
    }

    public function update()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $user = $this->_user;
            $user->email = $this->email;
            $user->username = $this->username;
            $user-> age = $this -> age;
            return $user->save();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

You mean this? it's situated in the same directory with actionUpdate.
But how can i use it in the view(profile/update.php)? 'Coz i try to update the Image from the view(profile/update.php) and use actionUpdate. Maybe there have another ways to do it?
    ...

```
public function actionUpload()
    {
        $user = $this->findModel();
        $model = new User($user);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->update()) {
            $imageName = rand(1000,100000);
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');

            $model->img =''.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension; //тут возникает ошибка Trying to get property of non-object
            $model->file->saveAs('uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
            $model->file = null;
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
...
```

**QUESTION UPDATED**
code from vendor/kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base/FileInput

```
<?php

/**
 * @copyright Copyright &copy; Kartik Visweswaran, Krajee.com, 2014 - 2016
 * @package yii2-widgets
 * @subpackage yii2-widget-fileinput
 * @version 1.0.5
 */

namespace kartik\file;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\base\InputWidget;
use kartik\base\TranslationTrait;

/**
 * Wrapper for the Bootstrap FileInput JQuery Plugin by Krajee. The FileInput widget is styled for Bootstrap 3.0 with
 * ability to multiple file selection and preview, format button styles and inputs. Runs on all modern browsers
 * supporting HTML5 File Inputs and File Processing API. For browser versions IE9 and below, this widget will
 * gracefully degrade to normal HTML file input.
 *
 * @see http://plugins.krajee.com/bootstrap-fileinput
 * @see https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput
 *
 * @author Kartik Visweswaran <kartikv2@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 * @see http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/examples
 */
class FileInput extends InputWidget
{
    use TranslationTrait;

    /**
     * @var bool whether to resize images on client side
     */
    public $resizeImages = false;

    /**
     * @var bool whether to load sortable plugin to rearrange initial preview images on client side
     */
    public $sortThumbs = true;

    /**
     * @var bool whether to load dom purify plugin to purify HTML content in purfiy
     */
    public $purifyHtml = true;

    /**
     * @var bool whether to show 'plugin unsupported' message for IE browser versions 9 & below
     */
    public $showMessage = true;

    /*
     * @var array HTML attributes for the container for the warning
     * message for browsers running IE9 and below.
     */
    public $messageOptions = ['class' => 'alert alert-warning'];

    /**
     * @var array the internalization configuration for this widget
     */
    public $i18n = [];

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public $pluginName = 'fileinput';

    /**
     * @var array the list of inbuilt themes
     */
    private static $_themes = ['fa', 'gly'];

    /**
     * @var array initialize the FileInput widget
     */
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->_msgCat = 'fileinput';
        $this->initI18N(__DIR__);
        $this->initLanguage();
        $this->registerAssets();
        if ($this->pluginLoading) {
            Html::addCssClass($this->options, 'file-loading');
        }
        $input = $this->getInput('fileInput');
        $script = 'document.getElementById("' . $this->options['id'] . '").className.replace(/\bfile-loading\b/,"");';
        if ($this->showMessage) {
            $validation = ArrayHelper::getValue($this->pluginOptions, 'showPreview', true) ?
                Yii::t('fileinput', 'file preview and multiple file upload') :
                Yii::t('fileinput', 'multiple file upload');
            $message = '<strong>' . Yii::t('fileinput', 'Note:') . '</strong> ' .
                Yii::t(
                    'fileinput',
                    'Your browser does not support {validation}. Try an alternative or more recent browser to access these features.',
                    ['validation' => $validation]
                );
            $content = Html::tag('div', $message, $this->messageOptions) . "<script>{$script};</script>";
            $input .= "\n" . $this->validateIE($content);
        }
        echo $input;
    }

    /**
     * Validates and returns content based on IE browser version validation
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @param string $validation
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function validateIE($content, $validation = 'lt IE 10')
    {
        return "<!--[if {$validation}]><br>{$content}<![endif]-->";
    }

    /**
     * Registers the asset bundle and locale
     */
    public function registerAssetBundle()
    {
        $view = $this->getView();
        if ($this->resizeImages) {
            CanvasBlobAsset::register($view);
            $this->pluginOptions['resizeImage'] = true;
        }
        $theme = ArrayHelper::getValue($this->pluginOptions, 'theme');
        if (!empty($theme) && in_array($theme, self::$_themes)) {
            FileInputThemeAsset::register($view)->addTheme($theme);
        }
        if ($this->sortThumbs) {
            SortableAsset::register($view);
        }
        if ($this->purifyHtml) {
            DomPurifyAsset::register($view);
            $this->pluginOptions['purifyHtml'] = true;
        }
        FileInputAsset::register($view)->addLanguage($this->language, '', 'js/locales');
    }

    /**
     * Registers the needed assets
     */
    public function registerAssets()
    {
        $this->registerAssetBundle();
        $this->registerPlugin($this->pluginName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are using a custom input widget, which uploads to a different url (/uploads). you didn't show the code for this specific /uploads action.
need more information.

btw, "<" in JSON looks like you are returning HTML instead of json. maybe you are throwing an exception. check it in your runtime/logs.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help i have update question. I am using this https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput widget. And i have add code from this widget(from my vendor/kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base/FileInput)

Comment: you are still hiding your controller action for handling uploads specified in 'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/site/file-upload']),

Comment: I have update question and add actionUpload. I thought no one wants to help me. Thank u. My faith is still alive)

Comment: maybe typo? your action is "function actionUpload", but your widget setting is to Url::to(['/uploads'])

Answer (score 0):

You have to instead
'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/uploads']),
Put the address of the action you want to upload the photo
'uploadUrl' => file-upload.php,